# How to check in c# code if the current project is xamarin or not?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am looking for a preprocessor symbol that would allow me to compile different code based on whether a project is xamarin or not.

```cs
void a()
{
#if XAMARIN
    b();
#else
    c();
#endif
}
```

Comment: `__MOBILE__` is pre-defined for Xamarin iOS/Android projects:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation#conditional-compilation

Comment: @SushiHangover I want it to work correctly with uwp as well. And these preprocessor symbols are not present in the common project.

Comment: As Cheesebaron suggests, you will need to define your own symbols then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use preprocessor symbols, but abstract stuff in separate classes for each platform. Then inject the specific implementation at runtime.

If you really must use these, you can always define your own symbols as needed for each configuration or target framework.

Just create a file called `Directory.Build.targets` (casing matters!) in the root of your repo. Usually next to your `.sln` file.

In this `Directory.Build.targets` you can define symbols like so:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETSTANDARD;PORTABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NET;WPF;XAML</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('uap'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETFX_CORE;XAML;WINDOWS;WINDOWS_UWP;UWP</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('xamarin.ios'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;UIKIT;COCOA;APPLE;IOS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('xamarin.mac'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;COCOA;APPLE;MAC</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('xamarin.tvos'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;COCOA;APPLE;TVOS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('xamarin.watchos'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;COCOA;APPLE;WATCHOS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('monoandroid'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;ANDROID</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'monoandroid10.0'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;ANDROID;__ANDROID_29__;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETCORE;NETCOREAPP</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp3.'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);WPF</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('tizen'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);TIZEN</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you can use these in your project as needed:

```cs
#if PORTABLE
   // do portable stuff
#elif UWP
   // do uwp stuff
#endif
```